# App crashing on sending a optional value while presenting a view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation

Please refer below code,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value: String?
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    let notification = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "post")).receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Button {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "post"), object: nil, userInfo: ["value": "Jeeva"])
                    debugPrint("Post triggered")
                    self.isPresented.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Post")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text(value!)
        }
        .onReceive(notification) { output in
            guard let out = output.userInfo else {
                debugPrint("no output")
                return
            }
            self.value = out["value"] as? String
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to open a view consists of a String `value`

By default, `value` is an optional String, I'll get the value in a notification and assigning that value to the variable `value` using `onReceive` modifier.

After assigning the value, I'm toggling the`isPresent` variable, which will trigger the `fullScreenCover`

Once the `fullScreenCover` triggered, app is getting crashed!

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: `Text(value ?? "no string" )`

Comment: 1. This is displaying "no string" all the time, But I've already set the "value" as "jeeva" in the ".onReceive" 
2. In my real project, I'm showing a view with ".environmentObject" inside the ".fullScreenCover" where the environment object was force unwrapped and leading to app crash. P.s: environment object was assigned in the ".onReceive"

Comment: Try .fullScreenCover(item:)